# Mouseup and mousemove events fail when used in an external module

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm working on a three.js project that implements some fairly standard orbit controls on an object (in this case a particle cloud).

When I use this logic within my root class (i.e. with all the three.js code) it works perfectly. However what I'd like to do is abstract this logic into an external class so it's out of the way.

When I do this, my `mousemove` and `mouseup` events do not fire. However, the touch events all fire perfectly and the orbit works as expected.

I've tried working with `preventDefault()` in the calls and it doesn't seem to make much difference. I've also tried using 'window' in place of 'document' as we're now in a module, but that didn't seem to work either.

What am I missing? The module looks like this:

```
var orbitElement;
var targetRotation = 0;
var targetRotationOnMouseDown = 0;
var mouseX = 0;
var mouseXOnMouseDown = 0;
var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

var Controls = {

    enableOrbiting: function(target) {
        orbitElement = target;
        document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', this.onDocumentMouseDown, false );
        document.addEventListener( 'touchstart', this.onDocumentTouchStart, false );
        document.addEventListener( 'touchmove', this.onDocumentTouchMove, false );
    },

    onDocumentMouseDown: function( event ) {
        document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', this.onDocumentMouseMove, false );
        document.addEventListener( 'mouseup', this.onDocumentMouseUp, false );
        document.addEventListener( 'mouseout', this.onDocumentMouseOut, false );
        mouseXOnMouseDown = event.clientX - windowHalfX;
        targetRotationOnMouseDown = targetRotation;
    },

    onDocumentMouseMove: function( event ) {
        mouseX = event.clientX - windowHalfX;
        targetRotation = targetRotationOnMouseDown + ( mouseX - mouseXOnMouseDown ) * 0.02;
    },

    onDocumentMouseUp: function( event ) {
        document.removeEventListener( 'mousemove', this.onDocumentMouseMove, false );
        document.removeEventListener( 'mouseup', this.onDocumentMouseUp, false );
        document.removeEventListener( 'mouseout', this.onDocumentMouseOut, false );
    },

    onDocumentMouseOut:function( event ) {
        document.removeEventListener( 'mousemove', this.onDocumentMouseMove, false );
        document.removeEventListener( 'mouseup', this.onDocumentMouseUp, false );
        document.removeEventListener( 'mouseout', this.onDocumentMouseOut, false );
    },

    onDocumentTouchStart: function( event ) {
        if ( event.touches.length == 1 ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            mouseXOnMouseDown = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - windowHalfX;
            targetRotationOnMouseDown = targetRotation;
        }
    },

    onDocumentTouchMove: function( event ) {
            if ( event.touches.length == 1 ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            mouseX = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - windowHalfX;
            targetRotation = targetRotationOnMouseDown + ( mouseX - mouseXOnMouseDown ) * 0.05;
        }
    },

    updateOrbit: function() {
        orbitElement.rotation.y  += ( targetRotation - orbitElement.rotation.y ) * 0.04;
    }
}

module.exports = Controls;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` is not what you think it is.

When you call `controls.enableOrbiting()`, then inside `enableOrbiting`, `this` is the same as `controls`. But when you register `this.onDocumentMouseDown` as an event handler, `this` inside `onDocumentMouseDown` is equal to the event emitter, that is `document`, not `controls`.

**EDIT: bind to `Controls` after it has been assigned.**

You can bind each function to `Controls`, like this:

```
var Controls = {}
Controls.onDocumentMouseDown = function (event) {
 ...
}.bind(Controls);
```

This way `this` will always be `Controls`, regardless of the `this` used in the method's invocation.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I tried using bind() but in doing so noticed I could be more explicit in my function ref as this is effectively a static helper class: 

`document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', Controls.onDocumentMouseDown, false );`

Is there any downside to this approach?

Comment: Absolutely no downsides. This is essentially a form of the common `var self = this` that saves `this` in the function's closure. Of course, in that case care must be taken that `self` is used consistently everywhere.

Comment: Cool. Both valid approaches then, this is now working great. Thanks!